# Send reset_password_instructions manually with devise 3.1.1 rails

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using devise 3.1.1 and trying to send a reset_password_instructions

```
Devise::Mailer.reset_password_instructions(@user, opts = {}).deliver
```

The mail is been sent but the @token is empty
I am tracing the @resource and the field reset_password_token is nil, 
when I am trying to generate a reset_password_token

```
@user.generate_password_token
User::generate_password_token
```

Both are giving me a no method error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
@user.send_reset_password_instructions
```

It's in [Devise's documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Recoverable).